# MS Access SQL - Compare General Date to Short Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to compare the 2 different date types (**General Date** & **Short Date**).

I tried to use **FORMAT()** to able to get the converted date, but you can't use it in WHERE Clause.

```
"SELECT DT, Item, N, InvoiceNum, FORMAT(DT, 'Short Date') as DT_SD FROM itemHistory WHERE DT_SD='#" & selectedDate & "#')"
```

Comment: You can't use an alias in a WHERE clause. Use the full expression instead, FORMAT(DT, 'Short Date')

Comment: This?

`SELECT FORMAT(DT, 'Short Date') FROM itemHistory`

Comment: You can't use that alias because your alias in your select unless you wrap your query with subquery.. `SELECT DT, Item, N, InvoiceNum, FORMAT(DT, 'Short Date') as DT_SD FROM itemHistory WHERE FORMAT(DT, 'Short Date') ='#" & selectedDate & "#')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Alias in your where because your alias use in your select. Unless you wrap in to subquery

Reason :

> Where : conditions are evaluated and rows that do not match are removed

So your `where` statement see as your row not your aliasing. Use the full expression instead as stated by @Rene.

```
"SELECT DT, Item, N, InvoiceNum FROM itemHistory 
WHERE FORMAT(DT, 'Short Date') = #" & selectedDate & "#)"
```

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work, but I fixed that by removing the apostrophes around the selectedDate, so it looks like this `#" & selectedDate & "#`. That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

You should always handle dates as dates, not text.

For Access SQL, you will have to use a properly formatted *string expression* for the date values:

```
"SELECT DT, Item, N, InvoiceNum FROM itemHistory WHERE DateDiff('d', DT, #" & Format(selectedDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) = 0"
```

If DT never contains a *time value*, this can be reduced to:

```
"SELECT DT, Item, N, InvoiceNum FROM itemHistory WHERE DT = #" & Format(selectedDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

This will run faster, if you have an index on field DT.

Comment: I tried your codes and it gives me an error.

`The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.`

And does ***General Date** Date Type is actually a **yyyy\mm\dd**? because it looks like this `6/16/2006 6:16:16 AM`

Comment: btw, I fixed your code by removing the extra comma between the InvoiceNum and FROM, but still it didn't show all my records.

Comment: Removed the comma, thanks. If records are missing using the first code, the dates (DT) do not match your selectedDate.